# Can I call finish() of an activity through adb shell command?

Tags: android, adb

I want to invoke the `onDestroy()` callback of an activity through adb command.
Can anyone let me know if there is a way to call `finish()` of an activity through adb shell command?

Comment: Maybe something like this?: `adb shell am force-stop 'your package name/.MainActivity'` or Using `kill` instead of `force-stop`.

Answer (score 7):

Unless you have overriden `onBackPress` for that activity,

You can use the back button key event to destroy the activity:

```
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

[SOURCE](https://gist.github.com/arjunv/2bbcca9a1a1c127749f8dcb6d36fb0bc)

You also have

```
adb shell am force-stop "package.name"
```

and

```
adb shell am kill "package.name"
```

But those commands will not trigger `onDestroy`, they will just kill the process, Plus the `am kill` only kills processes that are safe to kill (Meaning a process with no running services or activities).

Answer (score 0):

You can finish your app which will close the activity:

`adb shell am kill 'your package name'`